# Django object / Sql problem

Tags: django, django-models

I am just beginning to use Django, and I am having problems.

I would like to translate the following SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM modelName WHERE email=request.form['email']
```

into Django object code

```
uid = modelName.objects.(whatever goes in here)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query returns a list of `id`. Here is the Django version:

```
list_id = modelClass.objects.filter(email=request.form['email']).values_list('id', flat=True)
```